# SQLAlchemy - show creation statement with indexes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working with a database system that will require me to run the `CREATE TABLE` manually on several nodes.  This means I need to be able to obtain the `CREATE` statement, complete with indexes.

The following works to get the base schema:

```
from calendars import models
from app import db
from sqlalchemy import CreateTable

print(CreateTable(models.Calendar.__table__).compile(db.engine))
```

However, it does NOT print constraints or indexes.

How do I also obtain those?

Comment: What constraints does it not handle? In other words, what is `Calendar` like? For indexes try `CreateIndex` mapped over `models.Calendar.__table__.indexes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set sqlalchemy logging to debug, you can read statements from logs.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```